# Hiding/Removing business names & markers in react-native-maps' mapview

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps, mapview

I'm implementing my custom marker pin in MapView component. Are there a way to hide or remove third party markers, like hotels, restaurants, sales stores, etc...?

I have searched in component docs but found nothing.

Answer (score 9):

As far as I know, there is one way to turn off the business texts and markers. It is when we are applying a style to `<MapView>`'s `customMapStyle` property.

From this site, https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/
, skip to styling selecting "use the Legacy JSON styling wizard"
[image]

Then select "more options" for a more specific styling.
[image]

Select Points of Interest, then select Business, then select Text fill and Text Outline and make their visibility as hidden.
[image]

We'll click "Finish" button, then "copy JSON" button. Now we have JSON formatted data copied.
[image]

You may hold this info in a variable named, say `mapStyle`

```
mapStyle=
[
  {
    "featureType": "poi.business",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.business",
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The last thing to do is to use `mapStyle` and making it equal to `customMapStyle` property like this..

```
<MapView 
  customMapStyle={mapStyle}

  {/*other properties*/}   
 />
```

Comment: Thanks Uygar, worked as spected.