How to disable labels in react native maps (IOS)
I'm using react native maps for my react native mobile application. On android, the map renders as apple maps. I don't want any of the labels like New York, etc. I just want a blank map. Is there a way to do this? Thank you!


Weirdly enough, i don't think react-native-map supports the disabling of the labels but however, maybe its worth looking at this stackOverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73859535/hiding-removing-business-names-markers-in-react-native-maps-mapview
